# I am getting an error with hashlib module

Tags: python, error-handling, hashlib

I searched on google and found that it is pre installed and need not to be installed using pip
But when I ran a program writing by watching youtube but when i ran it gave me error

```
> Enter md5 hash: b73bf7d3ba1a517644661bc4bcd85f9a 
> File name: passlist.txt
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "hack.py", line 20, in <module>
> digest = hashlib.md5(enc_wrd()).hexdigest() TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable
```

but it showed this error bytes not callable sometimes freezed

This is my code:

```
import hashlib

flag = 0
counter = 0

pass_hash = input("Enter md5 hash: ")

wordlist = input("File name: ")

try:
    pass_file = open(wordlist, "r")

except:
    print("No file found")
    quit()

for word in pass_file:

    enc_wrd = word.encode('utf-8')
    digest = hashlib.md5(enc_wrd()).hexdigest()

    if digest == pass_hash:
        print("Password found")
        print("Password:" + word)
        flag = 1
        break

if flag == 0:
    print("Password is not in list")
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `digest = hashlib.md5(enc_wrd()).hexdigest()` with `digest = hashlib.md5(enc_wrd).hexdigest()` because `enc_wrd` is bytes and you can't call it.